# What is the best practice for redirecting users when sites are being upgraded?

Tags: redirect, upgrade, best-practices

We have an upgrade to an application coming up which requires a site collection to be deleted and recreated.  In terms of managing the existing users experience during upgrade what would be the best practice for redirecting requests for that site collection to a holding/maintenance page?

If it is under the root managed path of a web application would you just change IIS settings to redirect to a different URL?

If it is under another managed path within the web application then how could this best be managed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all requests go through a proxy server, and your proxy server supports this, create a rule that redirects all traffic for the web application, not just the entire domain, to a new temporary web page.

You can also take the low tech route and announce the change to your users by email.

Comment: This is probably the solution we will go with, but I was hoping there might be some other BP out there.

Comment: Accepted as the answer, as it is the approach we are having to take.  Though I am leaning more to Steve's concept as architecturally the right way forward.

Answer (score 4):

Or another option is to create a simple html page called **App_Offline.htm** and put it in the root of the virtual directory. No matter what page is hit, this page gets rendered. When you're done simply delete/nename it. I've only done this before for ASP.NET but it should work for SharePoint as it is build on top off asp.net. Must be .net 2.0 though.

Now if you have a heap of web front ends then this wont be the best method.

Check out [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/App_5F00_Offline.htm-and-working-around-the-_2200_IE-Friendly-Errors_2200_-feature) on this.

Comment: Good approach but as you pointed out not scalable across many WFEs

Comment: Does this have any impact though? Can the PowerShell and C# SharePoint API commands still interact correctly with the URLs when there's an app_offline.htm file present?

Answer (score 3):

You could also temporarily change the DNS to point to another server during the upgrade process. Make sure that you lower the TTL of the DNS records so that you quickly can switch back.

Comment: This would work but we'd rather make the redirect at the reverse proxy level if we can.

Comment: If you have a proxy in between its the way to go!

Comment: This would be a problem for any other site collections hosted on that server. Charles' question only mentioned a single specific site collection.

Comment: @Muhimbi Yea, I know. Consider it as a last resort..

Answer (score 2):

I've always created a httpmodule for this.

Comment: This requires web.config modification AND assembly deployment though.  Is there a reason you chose this over a redirect?

Comment: I chose this because it gives me the most control over who, how, and why I redirect.  It seems like your scenerio is only affecting a single site collection, so my thought would be to write a httpmodule that redirects only for that single site collection and then leave all the other site collections available.  All of the above options seem to be taking down your complete sharepoint site.  If your goal is to completely take down sharepoint during maintenance then I think the above options work well.  If you only need to take down a subset of sharepoint, I think the httpmodule is the way to go.

Comment: I addition to this, could you not package up the web.config mods into a feature (prob WebApplication scoped) which is activated before the upgrade and then de-activated after. that would take care of having to configure multiple front-ends individually

Comment: Definitely Paul.

Comment: There is a significant difference in the 'red tape' that is required to develop, test and deploy an additional code piece rather than have the infrastructure team configure reverse proxy settings.  Though I agree that if this had been considered from the outset your approach would have allowed additional flexibility.

Comment: The more I think about the flexibility this approach allows the more I think that this should be incorporated into our next project. +1

Comment: you would need to make sure that this would only redirect a subset of users. Otherwise the user carrying out the upgrade would be redirected as well.

Comment: Yep, that's what's nice about a httpmodule, it's completely flexible.  Also, I know for our environment, since we run ssl we have two iis websites connected to the same web application, one for search to use that doens't use ssl and the other for everyone else.  I often use the website that search uses for debugging and having an alternate web.config.  In this case one could not activate the httpmodule for the search website and then use that website for testing, deployment and other configuration.

Comment: But since he's upgrading an application, the most likely scenerio is that the site collection is being deleted and recreated through code in a solution, which the httpmodule wouldn't affect at all.

Answer (score 1):

We've been looking at doing something similar and have been looking at SPOffline from Codeplex http://spoffline.codeplex.com/

We haven't actually used it yet but it looks potentially useful.